# como agregar una condicion a un item de un JComboBox para mostrar otra JList? en JAVA

Tags: java

```
    if (comboCantidadGustos.getSelectedItem().equals(3)){
     modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Solo Vainilla");
     } else {
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Mousse de Limón");
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Frutilla a la Crema");
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Quinotos al Whisky");
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Chocolate con avellanas");
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Dulce de Leche");
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Sambayon con pasas");
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Crema Rusa con nueces");
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Crema Americana");
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Granizado");
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Vainilla");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perdon pense que era util esa informacion. Dado que no funciona este codigo

Comment: private void comboCantidadGustosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
       
        itemCantidadGustosCombo = comboCantidadGustos.getSelectedIndex();
    }

Comment: public void cargarListaGustos(){
    modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Mousse de Limón");
    modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Frutilla a la Crema");
    modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Quinotos al Whisky");
    modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Chocolate con avellanas");
    modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Dulce de Leche");
    }